# interoperability of encryption between C++ and C# with Crypto

Tags: c#, c++, qt, encryption, aes

I am trying to encrypt a string in C++ with Crypto++ lib in a Qt project and decrypt the same in C# in  a web application. Here is my code.

C++ Code, using Crypto++ lib

```
std::string Crypter::encrypt(const std::string& str_in, const std::string& key, const std::string& iv)
{
    std::string str_out;
    CryptoPP::CFB_Mode<CryptoPP::AES>::Encryption encryption((byte*)key.c_str(), key.length(), (byte*)iv.c_str());
    qDebug() << encryption.DefaultKeyLength();
    qDebug() << encryption.DefaultIVLength();


    CryptoPP::StringSource encryptor(str_in, true,
        new CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter(encryption,
            new CryptoPP::Base64Encoder(
                new CryptoPP::StringSink(str_out),
                false // do not append a newline
            )
        )
    );
    return str_out;
}
```

Calling the function here

```
std::string str = "123456789012345";
std::string key = "01234567891234560123456789123456"; // 32 bytes
std::string iv  = "0123456789123456"; // 16 bytes
std::string str_encrypted = c->encrypt(str, key, iv);
std::string str_decrypted = c->decrypt(str_encrypted, key, iv);
std::cout << "str_encrypted: " << str_encrypted << std::endl;
std::cout << "str_decrypted: " << str_decrypted << std::endl;
```

This code produces following result

```
Plain text: "123456789012345"
Encrypted value (base64): 3Qo/6hWctRiID3txA9nC
```

The same code I have written in C# here

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strOutput = Encrypt("123456789012345");
        Debug.WriteLine("Encrypted value is: " + strOutput);
    }

   private string Encrypt(string clearText)
    {
        byte[] clearBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(clearText + "\0");

        using (Aes encryptor =  Aes.Create("AES"))
        {
            encryptor.BlockSize = 128;
            encryptor.KeySize = 128;
            encryptor.Mode = CipherMode.CFB;
            encryptor.Key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("01234567891234560123456789123456");
            encryptor.IV = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("0123456789123456");
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(clearBytes, 0, clearBytes.Length);
                    cs.Close();
                }
                byte[] bt = ms.ToArray();
                clearText = Convert.ToBase64String(bt);
            }
        }
        return clearText;
    }
```

Which produces following result

```
Encrypted value is: 3YklwM2vG20ZmkOT029jTTL7FlSZHrh0RfvaT1FFa2k=
```

Can someone please suggest me what am I missing ? What is the correct way to get similar output from both languages.

My objective here is to encrypt a value in C++ and decrypt the same in C#.

### Edit

I did certain changes.

Replaced Hello world with 123456789012345
Changed the encoding from utf to Ascii
Added a null byte at the end of C# string
Change the mode to CFB

I have also edited the original result with the new result

Unfortunately, after doing this also, both the strings are not matching.

I have ensured that both the inputs are same.

Comment: Have you even tried to match the encryption schemes? If yes, you certainly haven´t tried hard enough.

Comment: What version of crypto++ are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your C++ code is in terms of `std::string`. That is most likely holding text encoded under an ANSI code page. When you pass it into that `CryptoPP::StringSource` I expect it works upon the bytes of that text directly without transforming it to any other encoding.

Your C# is passing the result of `Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes`. That means the encryption is working upon the bytes of UTF-16 encoded data.

Since the encodings are differerent, the byte representations are different. Then since the bytes are different, the encrypted result is different.

You need to get both pieces of code working under the same scheme.

If ANSI (or even just ASCII) characters are all that you want to deal with (which is probably the case given your C++ code), then you could modify the C# code to use `Encoding.Default.GetBytes` (or possibly `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes`) to get the bytes of the clearText.

---

EDIT

Looking further, your C++ code is using `CryptoPP::CFB_Mode` while your C# code is using `encryptor.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;`. Those modes need to match otherwise the algorithm will be applied differently.

You may need to go over other properties, such as padding, to ensure both are working under the same scheme.

Comment: `std::string` is a counted sequence of bytes, possibly including embedded NULs.  Text is its intended use, but it holds binary data just fine (unlike say `System::String^` which holds Unicode characters, not bytes)

Comment: Your point about different encodings of the input is valid though.

Comment: Definitely helpful, did some changes to ensure that same input is provided to both the encryption. However, the output is still different. Please look at the new edited question if if you could find something helpful

Answer (score 0):

There appear to be two underlying issues.  The following code will produce the same output as the CryptoCC library (`3Qo/6hWctRiID3txA9nC`):

```
byte[] clearBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(clearText);
using (var encryptor = RijndaelManaged.Create())
{
    encryptor.KeySize = 128;
    encryptor.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
    encryptor.Mode = CipherMode.CFB;
    encryptor.Key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("01234567891234560123456789123456");
    encryptor.IV = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("0123456789123456");
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
       using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            cs.Write(clearBytes, 0, clearBytes.Length);
            cs.Close();
        }
        Array.Copy(ms.ToArray(), clearBytes, clearBytes.Length);
        clearText = Convert.ToBase64String(clearBytes);
     }
 }
 return clearText;
```

Likewise, the following Crypto++ implementation will provide the value .NET returned in your example (`3YklwM2vG20ZmkOT029j`).

```
std::string encrypt(const std::string& str_in, const std::string& key, const std::string& iv)
{
std::string str_out;
CryptoPP::AES::Encryption e1((byte*)key.c_str(), key.length());
    // use feedback size of 1 byte.
CryptoPP::CFB_Mode_ExternalCipher::Encryption encryption(e1, (byte*)iv.c_str(), 1);


    CryptoPP::StringSource encryptor(str_in, true,
     new CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter(encryption,
        new CryptoPP::Base64Encoder(
            new CryptoPP::StringSink(str_out),
            false // do not append a newline
        )
     )
    );
    return str_out;
}
```

A few notes:

1. It's not necessary to append a trailing zero to the string.
2. The Crypto++ implementation does not allow padding in Cipher Feedback (CFB) mode.  The .NET implementation requires padding; however, the excess data can be truncated manually (as is done in the .NET example above).  (See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a1be5f49-5f0f-4f5f-b01c-af46fdc71915/des-encryption-cfb-mode).
3. See [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/2006/10/09/the-differences-between-rijndael-and-aes.aspx) on the implications of using AES in place of Rijndael as the CSP.  In particular, the following warning applies to CFB mode:

> Essentially, if you want to use RijndaelManaged as AES you need to make sure that:
>
> 1. The block size is set to 128 bits
> 2. You are not using CFB mode, or if you are the feedback size is also 128 bits

In this case, using CFB mode introduces additional complications.  Note that this is a consequence of using CFB; if you use Cipher Block Chaining (CBC) mode, both `Aes` and `Rijndael` return the same result as Crypto++ for the given key and value (`IwffxivpwdSuS9BV0KeyCg==`).

Comment: I managed to get it done. The actual issue with my code was of encoding. Using Ascii encoding resolved the issue well. Further, padding zer is an issue if the text length is less then block size.